# Adding items to list from DB and clear input after submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list that I get from DB and iterated with a `.map()`. I would like to add more items to this list and clear the input afterwards, so I can send back the "old list" with new items. How can I achieve this? Which is the best practice? It's a silly question, so I am sorry in advance.

```
this.state = {
  newRules: {
    rules: [],
    rulesTerm: ''
  }
};

handleInput = e => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  let name = e.target.name;
  console.log(value);
  console.log(name);

   this.setState(prevState => ({
     newRules: {
      ...prevState.newRules,
      [name]: value
     }
  }));
};

addRule = () => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let rules = this.state.field.rules;
  let newRules = this.state.newRules.rules

  rules.push(newRules)
  console.log(rules)

  this.setState({
    newRules: {
      rules: rules
    }
  }
 };

<ul>
  {this.state.db.rules.map(rule => {
    // this.state.db.rules is data from DB
     return <li key={rule}>{rule}</li>;
   })}
   {this.state.editMode ? (
     <form onSubmit={this.addRule}>
      <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder="regras"
        name="rules"
        onChange={this.handleRules}
        value={this.state.newRule}
      />
      <button type="submit">Adicionar +</button>
     </form>
   ) : null}
 </ul>;
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add two arrays together into a single array with the totality of array items, please check the [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method.

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(a1)        // [1, 2, 3, 4]
var a2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
console.log(a2)        // [5, 6, 7, 8]
var a3 = a1.concat(a2);
console.log(a3)        // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Everytime I click the submit button, I need to add one item and clean the input. @Peterson V

Answer (score 0):

approch 1:concat

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

console.log(array1.concat(array2));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

---

approach 2:splice

```
var months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(1, 0, 'Feb');
// inserts at 1st index position
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'June']
```